# Can function calls in a loop run after some function call after the loop declaration?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, lodash

Imagine the following code, running on node and using lodash:

```
var result = [];

_.each(someArray, function (elem) { ... result.push(newElem); });
_.each(anotherArray, function (elem) { ... result.push(newElem); });

superfunction(result);
```

Is it possible, in some circumstance, that `superfunction` runs before those each() finish, which means that `superfunction` would get an half filled `result` array?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. the result.push() could be in the callback of an asynchronous method, in which case superfunction would run before any of the .push() calls happen.

Comment: Ok, but, in the case of completely synchronous code on those functions called by the eachs - just some math calculations, for example - could the superfunction be called before the loops finish?

Comment: No. If it's synchronous, then it never leaves the current callstack and therefore superfunction can't run until the each is complete.

Comment: This is for all practical purposed asking if in the code `x(); y();`, could `y` run before `x` completes. No. JS is an imperative/sequential programming language that executes one statement at a time, in order.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless the statement that mutates `result` is executed asynchronously, for example as a result of a REST call.

Other than that, those lodash functions are completely synchronous.